# ViewChildren undefined on MatTabNavBar revisit

Tags: angular, angular10

I've a requirement wherein I'm using MatTabNavBar for displaying menu's on my screen. On my first menu, I try to load a component which has ViewChildren. On initial load this works fine, but as soon as the user tries to navigate to some other menu & than try to revisit the first menu it fails to initialize ViewChildren.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, but just in case someone else has this problem, I will post the solution I found.

This worked for me:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.queryList.first) {
        console.log(this.queryList.first);
    } else {
        this.queryList.changes.subscribe(() => {
            console.log(this.queryList.first);
        });
    }
}
```

where `queryList` is defined like this:

```js
@ViewChildren(/* selector */)
queryList: QueryList</* component type */>;
```

On initial load, `queryList` will be empty upon entering `ngAfterViewInit` and will be set once `this.queryList.changes` is triggered.

On subsequent loads, `this.queryList.changes` is not triggered again for some reason, but `queryList.first` is defined and can be used immediately in `ngAfterViewInit`.